# Can multiple HTML tags have the same ID if they are on different files?

Tags: html, tags

If they are on two different pages in the directory that contains the websites, within different HTML files, can they be given the same ID?

**Example**:

index.html:

```
<div id="exampleDiv"></div>
```

page2.html:

```
<div id="exampleDiv"></div> <!-- same ID as in index.html -->
```

Comment: @ianaya89 why should they not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you use the same id once for multiple html page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268249/can-you-use-the-same-id-once-for-multiple-html-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: Yes.

The `id` must be unique inside one file but not across different files (as long as not one file includes the other).

Answer (score 0):

If there are in different files for example `index.html` and `page2.html` they can have the same id's on both pages.

However if you are including `page2.html` into `index.html` then no you can not duplicate id's.

Answer (score 0):

yes they can. they only need the css file to be refrenced