# How do I create a popup in python?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I would like to know how to create a popup when I click the button.

I wrote the code using python and I loop the data that I need. And the data that came out I created a button to press and a popup would appear.

I'm not sure if the data I loop when I clicked on the popup button would show the details of the information I pressed.

I don't know what I need to do Please help recommend me I tried searching and trying for half a day but I really couldn't.

Here is my sample code.

And I've tried creating a popup and writing a script at order.html.

It can press the order button and the popup can only show in data1, but other data2,3,4,5.... cannot click the button and popup it does not show.

```
order.html

{% load cropping %}

<div>
      <p>{{ order.name }}<p>
    
      <button id="myBtn">ORDER</button>
</div>
<div id="myModal">
  <div class="show-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>
      Show menu info clicked #This will show the data of the data that I clicked on.
   </p>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
   var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
   var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
   var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

   btn.onclick = function() {
     modal.style.display = "block";
   }

   span.onclick = function() {
     modal.style.display = "none";
   }

   window.onclick = function(event) {
     if (event.target == modal) {
       modal.style.display = "none";
     }
  }
</script>
```

Please help recommend me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because you are using the same id of button multiple times.
Use event listeners instead. [Read this more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268249/can-you-use-the-same-id-once-for-multiple-html-page#:%7E:text=2%20Answers&text=An%20id%20should%20only%20be,%22top%20navigation%20bar%22).

Change your button have a class:

```
<button class="myBtn">ORDER</button>
```

and in script, ref it as

```
var btns = document.getElemenstByClassName("myBtn");
Array.from(btns).forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
  });
});
```

If you have different models for different orders, you may need to reference the specific one.

Comment: Thanks, But I have tried the method you suggested. But it still can't do.

Comment: I changed as you suggested. It can't be clicked and the message says --> TypeError: btn.on is not a function

Comment: I updated too in my code, But the message says --> (index):102 Uncaught TypeError: btn.addEventListener is not a function.

Comment: That was because document.getElementsByClassName was returning an array of elements. Edited code

Comment: I can do it. Thank you very much and I have a few more questions. Can you help me?

Comment: Surely, but Stackoverflow guidelines specifiy that one post should ask one related question. Subsequent can be in other questions. Would be happy to help out in them.

Comment: That is because your model doesn't understand whose data to fetch. Would recommend to move this to another question on SO

Comment: Ok, I will follow your suggestion. Thanks